# openmp conditional parallel loop

Tags: c++, openmp

I am trying to use an openmp for loop if a certain condition holds. I could simply use an if else statement to use the parallel for loop if a condition holds, but the code in the for loop is a bit long and it would double the length of the code if I just use the if else statement. So basically, I want a better way to do this:

```
if(condition_holds){
   // use parallel for loop
   #pragma omp parallel for
   for(...){
     // Long piece of code
   }
}else{
  // Don't use parallel for loop
  for(...){
    // Long piece of code
  }
}
```

so I won't have to write the code inside the for loop twice.

Comment: You can wrap your "long piece of code" with function or functional object, e.g. lambda. Both `for` loops will contain just a call.

Answer (score 23):

Use OpenMP's `if` clause to conditionally enable parallelism:

```
#pragma omp parallel for if(condition_holds)
for(...) {

}
```

You will probably get an overhead of one additional function call because the loop body is separated into a function by the OpenMP implementation.

Comment: Is there an equivalent of that for the Parallel Patterns Library (PPL)?

Comment: @user2399267......seemsgood Doesn't look like there is. But you have to call the parallel algorithms with a lambda or some kind of callable anyway, so you can capture it into a variable and call it in a loop from the `else` clause. This should be easy enough to templatize into a `parallel_for_if` algorithm...