# OpenMP - Running multithreaded vs singlethreaded based on parameter setting that is not #defined

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I need to test an application in both singlethreaded and multithreaded setting.

At present, I have a constant defined in a header file:

```
static constexpr char MT = 'y';
//MT = 'y' indicates I want to run multithreaded, 'n' indicates singlethreaded
```

I find myself facing a for loop where I would like to parallelize or not parallelize based on the setting of `MT`.

Is this possible within OpenMP?

Previously, I had

```
#define MT true //true means run multithreaded, false means run singlethreaded
```

This allowed me to handle the for loop thus:

```
#if MT
#pragma omp parallel for
#endif
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
         //do stuff here parallelly or not depending on #if MT check above
    }
```

Without `#define`'s and using `static constexpr`'s is it possible to obtain the equivalent functionality in OpenMP?

Comment: You can use environment variables to control OpenMP so you may be able to just use one binary (with the OpenMP pragma in it) to test both forms.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41450756/openmp-conditional-parallel-loop

Comment: @Anycorn Yes, that is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks.