# how to find the tradeoff between serial and parallel execution of for loop in C/C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc, openmp

I have a pretty large application with tons of OpenMP parallel loops where I make loops run in parallel using #pragma omp parallel for. However, it came to my notice that running loops with small iterations may not be worth running in parallel. Therefore, I decided to use OpenMP if clauses to be able to decide between serial and parallel execution.

On the other hand, cost of each loop's iteration can depend on program inputs and loop calculation data types (Eg. template functions). In other words, I seem to need a way, to be able to find out whether it is worthwhile to parallelize a loop up front at runtime.

Please please let me know what are C++ tools to better decide when to run an arbitrary loop in parallel or serial given the facts that

1. loop count is only known at runtime
2. loop calculation types can be a template variable.
3. number of threads available to the application is set only at the beginning of the application execution.

Much appreciate your valuable comments.

Comment: Profiling, and then you can limit the parallelization accordingly to some variable if(loop is big enough) then  #pragma omp parallel for. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/41450827/1366871

Comment: Yes but what if it is a template function, where the type of calculation (float, double) is not known before compile time and also the loop trip count is unknown before runtime, particularly if the loop count is a function of / depends on application's input. I guess there is no way unless as you said we profile the application for typical application's input and then based on the profiling outcome (loop's typical trip count / calculation type) we can decide what the thresholds are to put in if clause.

Comment: The other way might be to come up with a runtime heuristics as to measure the cost of creating a parallel region at the beginning of the application and then for each loop we encounter in runtime we convert that cost to the number of loop iterations and based on that number we can decide whether or not it is worth a parallel region for that specific loop. Please let me know your thoughts on that ... regards

Comment: That looks like a good idea, another possible idea is that in the template you can also add a weight, that weight would basically quantify how computational demanding the computation is, that combined with the loop count should give you a good estimation. You need to be careful to ensure that the heuristic itself does not add a high overhead. I am not expert in C++ so I am not sure how feasible this approach really is

Comment: You can use `#pragma omp parallel for if (...)` where the condition is a runtime one. So you can decide at run-time whether to execute a region in parallel or not.

Comment: @JimCownie I understand but I have no idea how to code/find/determine a reasonable tradeoff at runtime. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I managed to obtain the lower bound for maximum number of iterations one loop can do while serial execution outperforms parallel execution. However, I'd like you to kindly comment on that for us to see if there is a better way to find the right tradeoff/estimated number of a loop body iteration less than which it is not useful to benefit from a parallel for region. (many thanks

Let say:

N: is the number of threads in the parallel region running the loop.

R: is the cost of opening and closing a parallel region (measured by number of the loop iterations instead of nanoseconds for the sake simiplicity. )

S: is the maximum number of iterations (the tradeoff) more than which serial execution would take as much time as parallel execution (including the parallel region overhead).

So basically we are looking for S such that : parallel execution time = serial execution time. which would be: R + S/N = S.

When solved for S then: S = R x N / (N-1). So I tested the idea using the below code:

Where I do the below steps:

1. lines 78-96: the cost of creating/forking and finalizing/joining a parallel region is measured.
2. lines 99-111: the cost one iteration of the loop is measured.
3. lines 113-116 : the tradeoff is obtained using the formula discussed above.
4. line 119 : I run a test just to compare the parallel vs serial execution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>
// #include <ctime>
#include <chrono>

// #define dtype float
// #define NROWS 1350 // float
#define dtype double
#define NUMEL 1000 // double

#define NPAR_REGION 100000
#define TEST_REP 1000
#define NREP 1000

#define printvar(x) std::cout << #x << " = " << x << std::endl;
#define printline std::cout << "LINE: " << __LINE__ << std::endl;

// #pragma omp declare simd
template <typename T>
T loop_body_func(T x, T y){
    return sqrt(x*sin(x)/(1+y));
}

using namespace std;


int compare_seri_vs_para(int numel, int nrep){  
    dtype *m = (dtype*) malloc(sizeof(dtype)*numel) ;
    dtype *n = (dtype*) malloc(sizeof(dtype)*numel) ;
    dtype *mn = (dtype*) malloc(sizeof(dtype)*numel) ;

    int a;
    chrono::steady_clock::time_point st = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    #pragma noparallel
    for(int k = 0; k < nrep; k++){
        #pragma omp parallel for if (true)
        #pragma novector
        for(int i = 0; i < numel; i++){
            mn[i] = loop_body_func(m[i], n[i]);
            // if (i % 100 == 0){
            //  printvar(omp_get_thread_num());
            // }
        }
    }
    chrono::steady_clock::time_point en = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << "parallel ellapsed time: \t" <<
        chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(en - st).count() << std::endl;
    st = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    #pragma noparallel
    for(int k = 0; k < nrep; k++){
        #pragma noparallel
        #pragma novector
        for(int i = 0; i < numel; i++){
            mn[i] = loop_body_func(m[i], n[i]);
            // if (i % 100 == 0){
            //  printvar(omp_get_thread_num());
            // }
        }

    }
    en = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << "serial ellapsed time: \t\t" <<  
        chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(en - st).count() << std::endl;

    free(m); free(n); free(mn); 
    return 0;
}


int main(){
    printline
    int nthread = omp_get_max_threads ();
    printvar(nthread)
    // chrono::steady_clock::time_point  *thread_cost = 
    //  (chrono::steady_clock::time_point  *) calloc(nthread, sizeof(chrono::steady_clock::time_point));
    double *thread_cost = (double*) calloc(nthread, sizeof(double));
    chrono::steady_clock::time_point  sc = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    #pragma noparallel
    #pragma novector
    for(int i = 0; i < NPAR_REGION; i++){
        #pragma omp parallel
        {
            int tid = omp_get_thread_num();
            thread_cost[tid] += tid; // a dummy task        
            // chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(chrono::steady_clock::now() - sc).count()
        }
    }

    printline
    double paralell_region_cost = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(chrono::steady_clock::now() - sc).count();
    // for(int i = 0; i < nthread; i++) 
    //  paralell_region_cost+= thread_cost[i];
    paralell_region_cost /= NPAR_REGION;

    printvar(paralell_region_cost)
    printline

    dtype *m = (dtype*) malloc(sizeof(dtype)*TEST_REP) ;
    dtype *n = (dtype*) malloc(sizeof(dtype)*TEST_REP) ;
    dtype *mn = (dtype*) malloc(sizeof(dtype)*TEST_REP) ;

    sc = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    #pragma noparallel
    #pragma novector
    for(int i = 0; i < TEST_REP; i++){
        mn[i] = loop_body_func(m[i], n[i]);
    }
    double loop_body_cost = \
            chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(chrono::steady_clock::now() - sc).count()/TEST_REP;
    printvar(loop_body_cost)

    printline
    int loop_parallel_serial_tradeoff = (paralell_region_cost / loop_body_cost)*(nthread/(double(nthread)-1.0));
    printline
    printvar(loop_parallel_serial_tradeoff)

    printline
    compare_seri_vs_para(loop_parallel_serial_tradeoff, NREP);

    free(m); free(n); free(mn); 
    printvar("-=program ended!=-")
}
```

I compiled my code snippet using the below command line:

```
icl.exe -Qopt-report:5 -Qopt-report-phase:all /Ob0  -Qopenmp -Qsimd -Qopenmp-simd  -arch:avx2  -Qdiag-error-limit:5   -c omp_if_test.cpp -Fo:omp_if_test.obj
Intel(R) C++ Intel(R) 64 Compiler for applications running on Intel(R) 64, Version 19.1.2.254 Build 20200623
Copyright (C) 1985-2020 Intel Corporation.  All rights reserved.

icl: remark #10397: optimization reports are generated in *.optrpt files in the output location
omp_if_test.cpp
xilink.exe omp_if_test.obj -LIBPATH:../../Debug/lib -out:omp_if_test.exe
xilink: executing 'link'
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.28.29913.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

omp_if_test.obj
-LIBPATH:../../Debug/lib
-out:omp_if_test.exe
```

Finally, here is the output which is a bit odd as it seems serial always outperforms parallel execution almost 3 fold. (lol) (I was expecting a flactuating situation).

```
C:\simdtests>omp_if_test.exe
LINE: 72
nthread = 8
LINE: 90
paralell_region_cost = 2053.75
LINE: 97
loop_body_cost = 32
LINE: 113
LINE: 115
loop_parallel_serial_tradeoff = 73
LINE: 118
parallel ellapsed time:         3392300
serial ellapsed time:           1141000
"-=program ended!=-" = -=program ended!=-

C:\simdtests>omp_if_test.exe
LINE: 72
nthread = 8
LINE: 90
paralell_region_cost = 2304
LINE: 97
loop_body_cost = 33
LINE: 113
LINE: 115
loop_parallel_serial_tradeoff = 79
LINE: 118
parallel ellapsed time:         3275000
serial ellapsed time:           1216000
"-=program ended!=-" = -=program ended!=-

C:\simdtests>omp_if_test.exe
LINE: 72
nthread = 8
LINE: 90
paralell_region_cost = 2132.9
LINE: 97
loop_body_cost = 32
LINE: 113
LINE: 115
loop_parallel_serial_tradeoff = 76
LINE: 118
parallel ellapsed time:         3337900
serial ellapsed time:           1123100
"-=program ended!=-" = -=program ended!=-

C:\simdtests>omp_if_test.exe
LINE: 72
nthread = 8
LINE: 90
paralell_region_cost = 2062.77
LINE: 97
loop_body_cost = 32
LINE: 113
LINE: 115
loop_parallel_serial_tradeoff = 73
LINE: 118
parallel ellapsed time:         3739700
serial ellapsed time:           1118400
"-=program ended!=-" = -=program ended!=-

C:\simdtests>omp_if_test.exe
LINE: 72
nthread = 8
LINE: 90
paralell_region_cost = 2121.74
LINE: 97
loop_body_cost = 91
LINE: 113
LINE: 115
loop_parallel_serial_tradeoff = 26
LINE: 118
parallel ellapsed time:         5627200
serial ellapsed time:           356300
"-=program ended!=-" = -=program ended!=-
```

So it seems I obtained a lower bound for the tradeoff value as opposed to the actual value.

I would appreciate if you kindly comment on that for us.

Regards